# Poisson process at infinity

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Is the following probability well-defined?

> Let $(X_t)_{t>0}$ be Poisson process ~ (pt)

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}P(X_{N/(2p)}< N ) = ?$$

How do I deal with the fact that the time is infinite ($t=\frac{N}{2p}$) and the number of arrivals if infinite (N)?

Comment: Since this is related to your previous question [Limit of stochastic process](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031041/limit-of-stochastic-process), you should give a link and mention the connection.

Comment: sloven: Why are you masking the content of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but here's my best guess.
If $X_t$ is a Poisson process with intensity $p$, you seem to be asking about
the limit as $N \to \infty$ of ${\mathbb P}(X_{N/(2p)} < N)$.  Or maybe
it's asking about something like $\mathbb P(\lim_{N \to \infty} X_{N/(2p)}/N < 1)$.

Hint: $X_{N/(2p)}$ is the sum of $N$ independent Poisson random variables
$X_{1/(2p)}$, $X_{2/(2p)} - X_{1/(2p)}$, ..., $X_{N/(2p)} - X_{(N-1)/(2p)}$, each with expected value $1/2$.  Use the Laws of Large Numbers.  The Weak Law addresses the first question, and the Strong Law the second.

Comment: thx . still how the expectation helps me with caculating the probability

Comment: Which probability?  Why did you delete the formula in your question?